# Linux file system architecture

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need some good references about Linux "FileSystem" architecture and design patterns.Please refer me to article or some documents like "how to articles". I want to build FileSystem like(ext3 / ext4 / btrfs etc) from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your own filesystem by the means of [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) (Filesystem in Userspace). This way is relatively simple, because you don't need to implement kernel modules.

You can find example code [here](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html). This is a "dumb" filesystem which will, upon mounting, contain one file with the (hardcoded) contents "Hello World!". It's a good starting point, though.

You can use it as follows (from the main project page):

```
~/fuse/example$ mkdir /tmp/fuse
~/fuse/example$ ./hello /tmp/fuse
~/fuse/example$ ls -l /tmp/fuse
total 0
-r--r--r--  1 root root 13 Jan  1  1970 hello
~/fuse/example$ cat /tmp/fuse/hello
Hello World!
~/fuse/example$ fusermount -u /tmp/fuse
~/fuse/example$
```

Comment: Thank you,But what about Kernel Modules ? something that can be add to some of Linux Distro's ?